# How can I make my cat less lethal?

Tags: cats, hunting

I‌ get extremely annoyed when my cat comes back home with a beautiful dead bird (as it happened an hour ago).

There is a flap door in our house so the cat is free to go out. We don't wish to confine the cat inside. So please do not suggest that.

I'm wondering what are the most effective and humane ways to make hunting as difficult as possible for him? (cutting his nails short? hanging a bell on his neck? shouting at him? etc.)

Comment: Cats kill things. Consider letting your cat be a cat. How would you feel if your cat made you run around naked and bathe by licking yourself?

Answer (score 5):

Never shout at your cat. She will never understand what her fault is and will instead become afraid of you.

Your cat loves you and considers you part of family. This the reason she is doing this. Otherwise she would have finished her food alone. She wants to share her prized catch with you, and she thinks the sight of delicious food offered by her to you will make you happy and the two of you can together finish the food.

The cat is incapable of understanding that your dietary preferences are different.

And you have given an excellent solution in your own question. Putting a collar on your cat with a bell hanging will no longer keep your cat's movements stealthy. Prey will get alarmed before the predator can bring herself within striking distance.

It is like a deadly F35 with a loud siren to make all air defence systems go crazy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But is putting a bell really effective?‌ I‌ had read somewhere that it is not.

Comment: @Babr My cat has 3 bells on him. Does not help... I mean, maybe some animals are warned, but other are not.